# How to access symbol definition attributes to perform transformation in paperjs

Tags: paperjs

I am having issues rotating my symbol around a specific pivot point.

Here is my code :

```
    var path_tank_left_track = new Path({
      segments: [[0,0], [10, 0], [10,40], [0,40]], strokeColor: 'black',
      closed: true
    });

    var path_tank_right_track = new Path({
      segments: [[40,0], [50, 0], [50,40], [40,40]], strokeColor: 'black',
      closed: true
    });

    var path_tank_body = new Path({
      segments: [[10,5], [40,5], [40,35], [10,35]], strokeColor: 'black',
      closed: true
    });

    var path_tank_gun = new Path({
      segments: [[23,15], [23,0], [27, 0], [27, 15]],
      strokeColor: 'black',
      pivot: [25,15],
      name: 'gun'
    });

    var path_arena_separation = new Path(new Point(view.size.width/2,0),
    new Point(view.size.width/2, view.size.height));
    path_arena_separation.strokeColor = 'black';
    path_arena_separation.closed = true;

    var whole_tank = new Group();
    whole_tank.addChild(path_tank_left_track);
    whole tank.addChild(new Point(5,20)); // trying to add the middle of the left track pivot point
    whole_tank.addChild(path_tank_body);
    whole_tank.addChild(path_tank_right_track);
    whole tank.addChild(new Point(50,20)); // trying to add the middle of the right track pivot point
    whole_tank.addChild(path_tank_gun);

    // Create a symbol definition from the path:
    var definition = new SymbolDefinition(whole_tank);

    var instance1 = definition.place();
    instance1.position = new Point(view.size.width/4, view.size.height/2);
    var instance2 = definition.place();
    instance2.position = new Point(3*view.size.width/4, view.size.height/2);

    function onFrame(event) {
      instance1.rotate(1, instance1.definition.item.children[1]);
    }
```

As you can see, at the onFrame function, I'm trying to rotate the instance by 1 degree every frame around the point I created earlier. But I get an error saying the item_remove is not a function in the paper-full.js.

I'm confused, I tried to create a path with a single point and add it to the group but it did not let me.

If I modify the code to make the gun rotate on it's pivot instead, it does work :

```
function onFrame(event) {
  instance1.definition.item.children['gun'].rotate(1, instance1.definition.item.children['gun'].pivot);
}
```

The gun does rotate around the proper pivot and the pivot stays attached to the symbol even if the symbol moves around. How could I achieve that behavior but turning the whole tank around a specific point relative to the center of the tank?

Thank you for your help, let me know if I should include more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is crashing because you try to add a point (and not a path containing a single point as you seems to be trying to) as a group child, which is not what API expects.

To create a path containing a single point, you have to do this:

```
var path = new Path(new Point(x,y));
```

But I think the idea of adding a single point path as a child to later retrieve its position to use it as a pivot point is wrong in your case.
The fact that you are creating each tank as a `Symbol` implies that you won't have access to its own children.
You can instead, before placing your symbols, store 2 vectors: one from center to left and one from center to right. They will later help you calculating left / right track positions.

Here is a [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) adapted from your code, demonstrating this.

```
var path_tank_left_track = new Path({
    segments   : [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 10, 0 ], [ 10, 40 ], [ 0, 40 ] ],
    strokeColor: 'black',
    closed     : true
});

var path_tank_right_track = new Path({
    segments   : [ [ 40, 0 ], [ 50, 0 ], [ 50, 40 ], [ 40, 40 ] ],
    strokeColor: 'black',
    closed     : true
});

var path_tank_body = new Path({
    segments   : [ [ 10, 5 ], [ 40, 5 ], [ 40, 35 ], [ 10, 35 ] ],
    strokeColor: 'black',
    closed     : true
});

var path_tank_gun = new Path({
    segments   : [ [ 23, 15 ], [ 23, 0 ], [ 27, 0 ], [ 27, 15 ] ],
    strokeColor: 'black',
    pivot      : [ 25, 15 ],
    name       : 'gun'
});

var path_arena_separation         = new Path(new Point(view.size.width / 2, 0), new Point(view.size.width / 2, view.size.height));
path_arena_separation.strokeColor = 'black';
path_arena_separation.closed      = true;

var whole_tank = new Group();
whole_tank.addChild(path_tank_left_track);
whole_tank.addChild(path_tank_left_track);
whole_tank.addChild(path_tank_body);
whole_tank.addChild(path_tank_right_track);
whole_tank.addChild(path_tank_gun);

// store vectors from bounds center to tracks middle points
var tankCenter       = whole_tank.bounds.center;
var leftTrackCenter  = new Point(5, 20);
var rightTrackCenter = new Point(50, 20);
var leftVector       = leftTrackCenter - tankCenter;
var rightVector      = rightTrackCenter - tankCenter;

// Create a symbol definition from the path:
var definition = new SymbolDefinition(whole_tank);

var instance1      = definition.place();
instance1.position = new Point(view.size.width / 4, view.size.height / 2);
var instance2      = definition.place();
instance2.position = new Point(3 * view.size.width / 4, view.size.height / 2);

function onFrame(event)
{
    // calculate pivot point position
    // first we rotate vector accordingly to instance current rotation
    var rotatedVector = rightVector.rotate(instance1.rotation);
    // then we add it to current tank center
    var point = instance1.bounds.center + rotatedVector;

    // turn right
    instance1.rotate(1, point);
}
```